# findFirstVisibleItemPosition() always returned -1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I try to find that is my first item in `recyclerview` showed or no.
I use `findFirstVisibleItemPosition()` but it is always returned -1 when I scrolled `recyclerview`.
I use `recyclerview` inside `viewpager`.

```
val linearLayoutManager =
        LinearLayoutManager(container.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    recCafeList = binding.recCafeList

    recCafeList.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
    recCafeList.adapter = mAdapter

    val po = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    val po2 = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

    recCafeList.setOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            Log.i("scrollListener", "$po //// $po2")
        }

    })
```

Logcat:

```
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
I/scrollListener: -1 //// -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are storing the value of linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() and linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() initially only and then you are logging it in the setOnScrollListener.

Instead, this is what you should do.

```
val linearLayoutManager =
    LinearLayoutManager(container.context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
recCafeList = binding.recCafeList

recCafeList.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
recCafeList.adapter = mAdapter

recCafeList.setOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

        val po = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        val po2 = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

        Log.i("scrollListener", "$po //// $po2")
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You always show the values of the same variables withot changing their values.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() inside onScrolled callback method